# Is there a verb for being in context?

Tags: single-word-requests

If we check stackexchange tagging system, we have tags, which describe the context of the questions and answers or they describes what the question is about. For example we can have a question related to a PHP (programming language) feature. We can tag this question as `programming`, `php-5.x`, `map-reduce`. We don't have to type the "php" word to know that we are talking about a php feature, since it is in the tags, so we can consider those tags as context. On the other hand we have to talk about map reduce, which is the primary topic of the question, so it is not in the context and most probably the text will contain that term at least once. So we can tell, that the `question describes map-reduce`. I am looking for a similar verb which means that the context of the question is `programming` or `php-5.x`, so `question *verb programming` or `programming *verb question`. Is there such a verb, or is there a better way to describe this relationship than `is-context-of` / `is-in-context`?

Comment: It might help if you provided a sample sentence, using X to represent the word you are looking for. I can't tell if some form of [meileu](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/milieu) meets your needs.

Comment: In the example forms you've given a host of words like "regarding," "concerning," and "related to" would work, though they're not verbs.

Comment: Are you looking for something like *The "map-reduce" tag is [**contextualized**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+contextualized+to%22) to PHP?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, that's great: `question describes map-reduce` and `question is-contextualized-to programming and php-5.x`. Is this the proper way to use it? If so, then this is a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example phrases, it looks like you want a transitive verb, or a verb with an object.  The most appropriate that I can find is **concerns**.

> to relate to; be connected with; be of interest or importance to; affect

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/concern?s=t

> The question *concerns* php.

There are plenty of intransitive verbs, like **apply**, **pertain**, and a thesaurus could give you even more.  But then you would need a preoposition:

> The question **applies to** php.
>
> The question **pertains to** php.

Comment: Transitive verbs are better, but it does not need to be transitive. If I check the dictionary, "concern" roughly means "is about", so I wouldn't use that. The "applies to", "pertains to" might be okay. I accept this as solution, but I might stick with the "contextualize" word FumbleFingers suggested.

Comment: @inf3rno do you prefer the word "involves" to "concerns?"  It has this definition: "to include, contain, or comprehend within itself or its scope."  As in "the question **involves** php."

Comment: In my model the articles have tags, and some of the tags are describing the context of the actual article, while other tags are describing the content of the actual article. It is hard to separate these tags, since in a text every sentence can have different context, because the previous sentence can describe something new, which becomes context in the next sentence. I am using an RDF like graph, which means subject - predicate - object triples, and the subject and predicate are given (article or tag in any order), so the predicate should be different by these 2 type of relationships.

Comment: Probably the main difference between these tags: where did we define a concept and where did we use a concept in our content. This is really important if you want to build a semantic search engine... So `content defines/describes/is-about tag` and `content uses/applies/requires tag` will be okay. Thanks for helping thinking this through!